# How can we get AccessToken using AzureServiceTokenProvider for custom api protected with Azure AD?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get access token for my webapi which is protected using AAD.
I dont want to setup scope etc, just to authenticate

I already tried passing passing resource name

```
tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("http://testapi.azurewebsites.net/").Result;

var client = new HttpClient();

var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var accessToken=tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("http://testapi.azurewebsites.net");
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a whole article on the topic here: https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions.

You have to first setup at least one application permission in your API. 
Then assign the managed identity / dev environment client app that app permission.

When acquiring the token, you use the app ID URI or the client id of the API as the resource. 
If you are running the app in development environment, you will need to use a client id + secret or client id + certificate via the token provider connection string.

Comment: Hi Joonas, Having trouble following the article you mentioned.  how & where did you defined appRoles? I dont see any option other than manually uploading the manifest? where this "Things.Read.All" comes from?

Comment: Back then I manually defined them in the manifest. Nowadays it is possible to define them through the "App roles | Preview" tab on the API app registration in Azure AD.